# Does the address on my check need to match my return?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, payment

I need to send a check to the IRS. My check has a different address than the one I provided in forms 1040X and 1040. Is that okay or should the addresses match?

Comment: Not quite the same case, but for what it's worth, I've been using checks with an outdated address for 10+ years and have never had a problem. I don't think *anyone* even looks at the address on the check, unless of course the check doesn't clear.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to cross out the wrong address on the check and write in your current address.

Comment: Seriously, it's 2017. Don't use checks. They're the most insecure form of payment. If you really want to send money as paper on occasion, use cashier's checks for it so they don't include your account information that's easy for anyone who sees it to use and painful to change.

Comment: @R.. : Lots of businesses still use paper checks to pay bills.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't seem to me like they should care so long as it clears, but they instruct you to provide the correct info on the front of the check.

Here's [Everything You Need to Know About Making Federal Tax Payments](https://www.irs.gov/uac/everything-you-need-to-know-about-making-federal-tax-payments) from the horses mouth:

> Always provide on the front of your check or money order your correct
>   name, address, Social Security number listed first on the tax form,
>   daytime telephone number, tax year and form number

Note it doesn't say the address must be the same as anything you sent previously, just that it is correct.

Answer (score 5):

As long as the check clears, the IRS will not care whether the address on your checks match.

Comment: And as long as they can match the tax payment to the return, should the two be separated.  You may want to write your SSN on there.